# How does django call the .py files at root directory?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project that someone else started, and I'm new to Django, so I'm not sure about the workflow.

I see that there is a file called `load_fixtures.py` in the root directory (so the file is a sibling of `manage.py`) , but I don't understand why (and when) is that file called.

1. **When?** Does it get called only during `syncdb`?
2. **Why?** i.e. which file includes / calls it? Is it called just because it's in the root directory? Or does a line from `settings.py` include it?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Without knowing the full structure of the project, and the contents of each and every file, there is no possible way anyone could answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a part of a standard Django project and is not automatically called by Django itself. I guess it's just a standalone file that the developer created, to run from the command line to populate the db.

Comment: You are right, for some reason I skipped the possibility that this file was never called :)